# Fixed width records in one line

Tags: hadoop, fixed-width

I am currently working on a use case in which all the fixed width input records are present in one line. This file is huge enough to span multiple blocks on the hadoop cluster. 
How can i achieve this functionality to correctly read all records?

Comment: can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Could you please add an example, what kind of data in the file and how you want to access it?